# show ALL mail, sent and new, in outlook reading pane

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

i have conversations enabled as well as "show messages from other folders".  i would like all messages to appear in the reading pane as well (not just the tree list). for example, if i reply to X and i look at that message from the inbox, the reading pane view will only show the original message from X as well as indicate that "you replied to this message on..."  i want to see my reply without clicking on "find related messages" and without going into my sent folder. and without making a search folder.

is this possible?  thanks.

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using? In Outlook 2013, there is a Conversation view which let's you see all the e-mails grouped together.

Comment: outlook 2013.  i want to see all emails from a single conversation between myself and the other person in the reading pane.  right now, if the last action was a reply by me, i can't see that reply without going into sent mail.

Answer (score 1):

Try Conversation View with the settings below. It works well for me:

In Outlook 2013, go to View Ribbon (Messages section):

- Check on Show as Conversations
- Select on "Show Messages from Other Folders"
- Select on "Always Expand Selected Conversation"

[image]

I am in the inbox, but the Conversation View will also display your Sent Items e-mails as well in the thread:

[image]

Comment: Thanks...i think that's the best I can get.  I'd like for the text of the sent email to show up in the reading pane, but this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No way. Sorry. It can't be done in Outlook currently.

Comment: that's what i was afraid of...bummer